# Ubuntu 12.04 Routing question

Tags: networking

I have got a little network problem:

Samsung 350 v5c laptop.ubuntu 12.04

The problem is that if i use the wifi connection,because that is my internet connection at the moment,and if i want to use same time my Lan connection too,there is no internet.
So if i plug to another one router to the Lan interface no internet,if i unplug the router there is internet.

How should configure my network that working wlan and ethernet same time?

Answer (score 0):

Well first you should know that it will only work if you are on two different networks so for example your LAN on 192.168.1.120 and your wifi on 192.168.2.120. If you try to connect both to the same Network you will end up with no Internet at all.

So Wifi and LAN on same Network is a no go.

But if you still insist:

Open `Edit Connections` 
[image]

Click on the wired connection you want to edit and then on Edit. 
[image]

then on `IPv4 Settings` 
[image]

Click on `Method` and the `Manual` 
[image]

After you've done that you can give the IP of your other Network.
[image]

To check if you are connected to both networks do the following:

In the upper right corner open `Connection Information`
[image]

Here you can see both connections IP and further Information.
[image]
[image]

Comment: So,my network:Wifi network:192.168.0.1/24,Lan network:192.168.88.0/24,so if i connect to my wifi network,there is internet,but if i connect same time to my Mikrotik routerboard(192.168.88.1/24)there is no internet connection

Comment: yeah, but I would recommend something like 192.168.0.50/24 or 192.168.0.100/24 because the lower numbers .0,.1 and higher .255 are reserved for broadcast, router, default-gateway etc. could you give me the exact model of your Router?

Comment: I am living in London,and there is here an adsl connection,but i can not configurate only my Mikrotik 750 GL router,anyway in my connection information,there are 2 default connection,not this cause the problem?and i should configurate routing?

Comment: Hmm Well you see all you can do is create two Networks and connect to them, the thing is if you manage to get both connected to the same ADSL it will not affect your speed... If you want both on the same ADSL connection I would recommend to make a sub-net and then connect the wifi to the subnet. But as said before this will not affect your surfing speed... Here's a link regarding multiple networks on your device: [How to run multiple networks from a Mikrotik](http://networkingforintegrators.com/2013/01/how-to-run-multiple-networks-from-a-mikrotik/)

Comment: In my case i have got an adsl connection,this is an adsl router-modem,so i connecting to the wifi,and my Mikrotik routerboard using only without internet connection,i develop myself,i am alone learning the network basic,mostly with Mikrotik routerboards,but if i connected to wifi,and then plug to my Mikrotik router to the Lan interface,there is no internet connection

Comment: Yes that's because the computer is trying to connect to both networks... As you said "To Default Connections" Follow the steps on this [Link](http://networkingforintegrators.com/2013/01/how-to-run-multiple-networks-from-a-mikrotik/) and you should have connection on both wifi and LAN...

Comment: So,my configuration at the moment:Wlan:192.168.0.0/24,that is my Internet connection,i do not have access to this router,and my Mikrotik routerboard:192.168.2.0/24,this way working both connection at same time,and i have got internet connection via wlan

Comment: But i can not log in to Mikrotik router

Comment: In order to log into your Mikrotik you shoul be in the same Network . So if you dont remember wether you changed the IP-Address of your  Mikrotik you probable have to reset the router to its defaults. and to log in to the device you have to open a browser and type in the IP-Address located on the bottom of the device... I think the default IP of your device is 192.168.88.1
 but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes it is,192.168.88.1,so at the moment,i achieved that,i can use my Mikrotik RBs,750 GL,and 411GL,without laptop Atheros wifi,My connection is that at the moment:Adsl router-modem>>>Mikrotik 411 GL Wifi client>>>Mikrotik 750 GL>>>Laptop Lan interface